# Compute multiple Rectangles area intersect by a circle

Tags: differential-geometry, circles, simpsons-rule

I've a need to compute the area of single elements (dice) of a matrix like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKVSz.jpg

The matrix is composed by 'c' columns and 'r' rows and every element/rectangle has the same height and width of any other.

knowing the element (x,y) center, I can know if its vertex are: - All out of circle area - All inside the circle area or - Partially inside the circle area (ray = 75.000 micron)

My problem is how I can compute the area of dice that are intersectated by the circle and more in deep how I can can compute the area of the portion of dice dice inside the circle.

So, to make an example, to work on, I've a dice with

```
CenterX , CenterY               [  29870.4 ,  67144.9 ]
DieDimensionX, DieDimensionY    [  5430.52 ,  4320.54 ]
Coord of upper left corner (A)  [ 27155.14 , 69305.17 ]
Coord of upper rightcorner (B)  [ 32585.66 , 69305.17 ]
Coord of lower left corner (C)  [ 27155.14 , 64984.63 ]
Coord of lower right corner (D) [ 32585.66 , 64984.63 ]
```

For each coord I've computed the segment lenght from axis origin and 1 corner (on 4) is out of circle:

```
sqrt( (x^2) + (y^2) )

A: 74435.261920332
B: 76583.495783129    == >75.000 
C: 70430.133924738
D: 72696.81818259
```

Which is the area of this dice inside the circle? Or else: which is the percentage of the area of dice inside the reticule compared with a full dice? I've read something about 'Simpson rule' that could help me but I don't know (a) if this is the correct approach (b) neither how to apply it on my example.

Thanks to anyone that would be able to help me.

Ciao, Stefano

Comment: Do we know the coordinates of the intersection points $E$ and $F$?

Comment: I think best approach would be to bruteforce it by numerical approach. If you like fun, you can even use some [Monte Carlo method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method), e.g. like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pi_30K.gif), it is extremely easy to implement, but does converge slower.

Comment: Ciao @Adriano. I can compute the E(x,y) and F(x,y) intersection but then?

I'm sorry to bother you on this topic but I need to solve the matter and I have too few knowledges of trigonometric.

Ciao dtldarek. Most probably you're right but then I have to translate this approach with an algorithm but obviously I cannot compute any point inside the rectangle for any rectangle (on a single matrix I can have a variable numbers of dice from a minimum of 150 up to a maximum of 130.000)

Comment: In addition... I can eventually tolerate an aproximation computing the area of the triangle out of the dice but I would need then to distinguish which dice [A] has 3 on 4 corners out of circle [B] has 2 on 4 corners out of circle [C] has 1 on 4 corners out of circle and then which is the die position as I need to know with corner(s) is/are out of circle accordingly to their quadrant position... so if I would have a (let me wrote) generally purpouse approach implementable for any scenario, it would be simpliest.

Comment: @StefanoRadaelli Can you tell us the coordinates of $E$ and $F$? Also, what exactly is the radius of the circle (is it $75000$ or $75$)? I'm assuming all units are microns. Also, why do you compute the distances from each corner to the **origin**? Shouldn't it be the distance to the **center of the circle**? Is the circle centered at the origin?

Comment: Ciao @Adriano. With order:

- I've computed distance of each corner as I have the need to compute the area of each rectangle of the above example matrix. So wrote if I compute the distance for each corner and if each of these values are greather than radius then it means that then dice is entirerly out of circle, then if each of these values are smallest thant the radius, then it means that the die is entirerly inside the circle.

Comment: @Adriano and in addition coordx of F & E (x,y):

    **yF** = yC = yD = **64984.63**
    **xF** = sqrt ((75000 * 75000) - (yF * yF)) = **37443.26**

    **xE** = xB = xC = **32585.66**
    **yE** = sqrt ((75000 * 75000) - (xE * xE)) = **67551.27**

Last but not the least, ray is 75000 micron (and not 75)